# Append array to multi dimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've created a multidimensinal array which is suppose to hold different sections of news for instance popular and Recent news. i've therefore created a array like this where News is my class.

```
 var arrayNews = Array<Array<News>>()
```

After this i'm looping through my first JSON file like this

```
    for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {
        // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
        var newNewsObject = News(id: subJson["id"].intValue, title: subJson["title"].stringValue, link: subJson["url"].stringValue, imageLink: subJson["image_url"].stringValue, summary: subJson["news_text"].stringValue, date: subJson["date"].stringValue)


        arrayNews.append(newNewsObject)
    }
```

However i'm getting following error when i try to append it to the array?

```
cannot invoke append with an argument list of type (News)
```

**Testing answer**

```
var arrayNews = Array<Array<News>>()
let recentArray = [News]()

    for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {
        // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
        var newNewsObject = News(id: subJson["id"].intValue, title: subJson["title"].stringValue, link: subJson["url"].stringValue, imageLink: subJson["image_url"].stringValue, summary: subJson["news_text"].stringValue, date: subJson["date"].stringValue)


        recentArray.append(newNewsObject)
    }

    arrayNews.append(recentArray)
```

error message

```
immutable value of '[(News)] only has mutating members named append
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
var arrayNews = Array<Array<News>>()
```

you declare that you will have an array of arrays.

But then you append a new instance of a `News` object which is not an array.

So you should probably change your `arrayNews` variable to be an array of `News` objects:

```
var arrayNews = [News]()
```

Comment: i've added a test of the answer to my question, i getting a new error

Comment: Because you're using `let`, it declares a *constant* that you can't modify. You should use a variable (`var`) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`arrayNews` expects `Array` elements but you provide it with a `News` elements.

You can use the following creation of your current section array and then add it to your multi-dimensional array:

```
let sectionArray = [News]()
sectionArray.append(newNewsObject)
arrayNews.append(sectionArray)
```

Comment: sectionArray.append(newNewsObject)
arrayNews.append(sectionArray) should they both be in the loop?

Comment: well logically no, the section array should be in the loop and then added to the main array outside this loop